# 502 Gateway troubles (1-C Bitrix)

Tags: php, apache, bitrix

When im trying to login into admin panel its throwing me **502 - bad gateway**. Site is at 1-C Bitrix system.

Log:

> [Wed May 30 00:05:07.998250 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1940] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
>
> [Wed May 30 00:05:08.377884 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1940] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.6.31 configured — resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed May 30 00:05:08.377925 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1940] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Wed May 30 10:43:29.683709 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1940] AH00052: child pid 2150 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>
> [Wed May 30 10:47:18.967783 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1940] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
>
> [Wed May 30 10:47:20.068047 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2176] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.6.31 configured — resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed May 30 10:47:20.068110 2018] [core:notice] [pid 2176] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

What is the cause and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What actions preceded to this error? What changes u did before error start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting provider must  check their server, maybe it has not enough disk or memory space.
What about scale graph?
/bitrix/admin/scale_graph.php
Bitrix is very dependent on resources of software and hardware? and even of lan speed or provider services. Begin from memory and disk space.